# Large video delay with Nvidia T1000 (4GB) and Ricoh Theta Z1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, video, graphics-card

When streaming UHD (3840x1920@29.97fps) to a video output (using a Nvidia T1000 4Gb 1065MHz 128bit graphics card) via USB the video delay is large (30 seconds). Not only is it large, but the delay compounds and increases (maximum I've seen is ~5 minutes).

I think it may have to do with the GPU bus width and clock speed.

I've just tried halving the resolution and it ran with less delay (0,5 seconds ish). This has led me to believe it is GPU related but I'm still unsure.

Am I along the right lines?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could have been multiple things, but what it came down to was USB cable type.

For some strange reason the Ricoh camera came with a USB 2.0 - with a blue head! This was completely misleading because I immediately ruled that out as the cause of the buffering.

On Ubuntu, to check the USB version of a port run `lsusb` to see what buses are available for the computer as well as what buses they use.

From there you're able to run `lsusb -t` which lists the devices under each bus as well as the *speed* they run at. This speed can be used to determine whether a device is connected via USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 - since the transmission is throttled not by the USB port, but by the USB cable.

For 2.0, the speed will be `480M`, for 3.1 gen 2 the speed will be `10000M`.

From here you can diagnose a possible throttling point.